# JQuery add class to row based on a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am reading a data from SQL Server database and displaying it in the form of a table. However, I need help on how to add a styling to a row in a table based on a value of one of the attributes using jquery

The column has a class like so

```
<td>
     <span class="funding-eligible">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FundingEligibility)</span>
</td>
```

In the javascript file I have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($(".funding-eligible").text() == 1) {
        $(".funding-eligible").addClass("eligible")
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there only one element with class "funding-eligible"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `funding-eligible` class `.each()` then use `closest()` to get the parent row

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".funding-eligible").each(function(){            // .each to loop through elements 
       if(+$(this).text().trim() === 1){               // .trim() to avoid white-spaces , + here to covert the string to number
          $(this).closest('tr').addClass("eligible");  // .closest() to get the closest row
       }
    })
});
```

You can also use `.filter()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".funding-eligible").filter(function(){  // .filter to filter elements by condition returned
       return +$(this).text().trim() === 1;    // .trim() to avoid white-spaces , + here to covert the string to number
    }).closest('tr').addClass("eligible");     // .closest() to get the closest row
});
```

But.. Why you don't use a condition to add a class to row directly in your html before appending?? something like`<tr class="<?php echo ($eligible == 1) ? 'eligible' : '' ?>">`

Comment: @Mohammed-Yousef You are a messiah! I have been trying to figure this out all day. I also taught of using your suggested approach but am working with Asp.Net Core and it appears DisplayFor does not support htmlAttributes. In the meantime this works great but I will still try to implemented your suggested approach. Am very grateful

Comment: Your're totally welcome @KaptinKoda .. Have a great day :-)